# How to pass data from tableview cell

Tags: swift, tableview, segue, cell

I wanna segue indexPath.row of a tableview cell from one viewController to another viewController.

```
var index = 0

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    index = indexPath.row
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "cellIndex", sender: self)
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.destination is trackSavingViewController{
        let TSController = segue.destination as! trackSavingViewController
        TSController.indexCell = index
    }
}
```

But all the it dose is just passing the original value(index = 0), not the value of the selected row. What can I do to fix the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in prepare(for segue)

```
let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
TSController.indexCell = indexPath.row
```

Comment: Link your tableview to your viewcontroller class or your tableview has a different name when you named it

Answer (score 0):

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let Dvc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DataVC") as! DataVC

```
    Dvc.getRollNo = arrayStudent[indexPath.row].strRollNo
    Dvc.getName = arrayStudent[indexPath.row].strName

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Dvc, animated: true)
}
```